# Exchangeability and independence of random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, random

I have a question on the relation between exchangeability and independence between random variables. Consider the random vectors 
$$u_1:=
\begin{pmatrix}
\epsilon_{1}\\
\epsilon_2\\
\epsilon_3
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and
$$u_2:=
\begin{pmatrix}
\epsilon_{4}\\
\epsilon_5\\
\epsilon_6
\end{pmatrix}
$$
All random variables are defined on the same probability space and have the same support. Under which conditions (other than i.i.d.) we have

(1) $\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2,\epsilon_3,\epsilon_4,\epsilon_5,\epsilon_6$ exchangeable

**and**

(2) $u_1$ independent of $u_2$

?

I am confused on the following: of course, $\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2,\epsilon_3,\epsilon_4,\epsilon_5,\epsilon_6$ i.i.d. is sufficient to have (1) and (2). However, could there be other sufficient conditions? For example?

Comment: Further thoughts added to the question

Comment: Why the heavy rewritings *after* somebody posted an answer? Please avoid this.

Comment: Because the answer made me thinking about further clarifications. The question did not change, BTW. And I just added my first attempt of answering because the answer given below is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that iid is the only way (1) and (2) can hold.

First, the vector comprising any three of the $\epsilon_k$s is independent of the triple comprising the other three. Thus, for example, $(\epsilon_1,\epsilon_3,\epsilon_4)$ is independent of $(\epsilon_2,\epsilon_5,\epsilon_6)$. Marginalizing, $\epsilon_1$ is independent of $\epsilon_2$; and then by (1), any two of the $\epsilon_k$s are independent. Next, $(\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2,\epsilon_4)$ is independent of $(\epsilon_3,\epsilon_5,\epsilon_6)$, and marginalizing again, $(\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2)$ is independent of $\epsilon_3$. Since we already know that $\epsilon_1$ is independnet of $\epsilon_2$, it follows that $\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2,\epsilon_3$ are mutually independent. By (1), the same follows for any three of the $\epsilon_k$s. It is now a short step to conclude that the six $\epsilon_k$s are mutually independent, and of course they all have the same distribution by exchangeability.

Comment: Thanks. I have a question on your initial claim: why the vector comprising any three of the $\epsilon_k$ is independent of the triple comprising the other three? Exchangeability does not imply independence. In other words, $\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2, \epsilon_3$ could be dependent and exchangeable. The same for $\epsilon_4,\epsilon_5, \epsilon_6$. However, $\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2,\epsilon_3$ is independent of $\epsilon_4,\epsilon_5,\epsilon_6$

Comment: Moreover, $\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2, \epsilon_3$ independent of $\epsilon_4,\epsilon_5, \epsilon_6$ implies that (1) $\epsilon_1$ is independent of $\epsilon_4$ conditional on $\epsilon_2, \epsilon_3$, (2) $\epsilon_1$ is independent of $\epsilon_5$ conditional on $\epsilon_2, \epsilon_3$, etc

Comment: I have added some thoughts to the question

Comment: @STF: Because, for example, exchangeability implies that the joint distribution of $(\epsilon_1,\epsilon_3,\epsilon_4,\epsilon_2,\epsilon_5,\epsilon_6)$ is the same as that of $(\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2,\epsilon_3,\epsilon_4,\epsilon_5,\epsilon_6)$.

Comment: +1. Another way to see this is that the joint characteristic function $\varphi(t_1,t_2,t_3,t_4,t_5,t_6)$ is, on one hand, symmetric, on other hand, splits into a product of $\psi(t_1,t_2,t_3)$ and $\psi(t_4,t_5,t_6)$. Then it is a matter of simple transformations to show that it splits into a product of $\psi(t_i,0,0)$, $i=1,\dots,6$.